# Go to beginning of output command created - shortcut

Tags: linux, bash

I can scroll trough bash output using shift+pgup/pgdown.

But lets say, some command outputted lot of text, I have to pageup few times to go to beginning of output of this command.

Can I just simply do this by some shortcut? Something that simply allows me to scroll between previous commands (not history!), seeing their output.

Comment: What terminal are you using? This is a feature of your terminal, not of your shell.

Comment: curently im using ssh, putty.

Answer (score 5):

You could try piping the output into [less](http://ss64.com/bash/less.html):

```
someCommand | less
```

less will allow you to search and scroll through the output text pretty easily.

once in less you can just type `%` to jump back to the top of the page. Essentially that means jump to `0%` of the page. There are also a bunch of extra commands on the page I linked to above.

Comment: But i woudl be able to use this only for current command, not previous ones.

Comment: that is correct. If you are looking to scroll back through old output, that is going to be more dependent on the terminal you are using. What operating system are you using?

Comment: Is there some way to do something like this, but using vi or vim?

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use [`screen`](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html) and use [backward search](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Searching) (beware: read the [Overview](http://www.gnu.org/software/screen/manual/screen.html#Overview) first, especially the part about the `C-a` prefix) to e.g. search for some specific characters in your prompt (like your username).

Answer (score 0):

The scroll back history in Unix shells is a shell specific functionality, meaning that it is up to the specific shell (xterm, rxvt, text console, etc) to handle it. The functionality you request would require the shell to identify the individual program runs, to know where to scroll to. Scanning text is not technically hard per se, but as prompts and command display can differ due to user settings it can be hard to make it work generally good. Some communication between the shell and the terminal could make it better.

There sure are some nice fancy terminal programs doing things like this, to for example show syntax help when writing commands, but for your case I agree with previous answer, that piping commands to `less` is a good way to isolate the output. It might be a bit cumbersome first, as it requires you to think about it first, and not just go back in history, but if you learn the shell better and learn to use the command history it will probably work fine. I recommend you to, if you haven't already. What I mean is `ctrl-r` etc. More described for example here:

http://www.catonmat.net/blog/the-definitive-guide-to-bash-command-line-history/